# RX IObserver subscription timing

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I'm new to Rx in .net but have started using it with some success wrapping up some network communication

*Very* simplified example:

```
    IObservable<Result> SendRequest(Request request)
    {
        return Observable.Create<Result>(observer =>
        {
            NetworkComms.SendReqeust(request,
                result =>
                {
                    observer.OnNext(result);
                    observer.OnCompleted();
                });
            return Disposable.Empty;
        }).SubscribeOn(_commsScheduler);
    }
```

The issue I have is that the command (NetworkComms.SendRequest) is not actually sent until the caller subscribes to the returned IObservable. In some cases the request is fire-and-forget command and the result is pretty meaningless, so it makes little sense for the caller to actually subscribe to the returned IObservable.

The functionality I need is:

1. The command is sent immediately, even if the caller never subscribes to the IObservable
2. If and when the client subscribes, they will get the result even if they are late subscribing
3. The command is only ever sent once, but all subscriptions should get the same results.

I tried doing this using .Replay().RefCount() and doing a Subscribe() internally before returning the IObservable. This almost works, but in the case where the client subscribes *after* the result received (and thus after the auto-disposing of the sequence on completion) it causes the subscription code to be called again, sending the command for a second time.

Is there a simple Rx extension that can handle this scenario for me, or do I need to roll my own?

Comment: This is a really rather odd what to compose this observable. You're kind of saying that I'll run this request now and then until the end of time (or when the app closes down) return me the result, no matter how stale it is.

Comment: You also shouldn't do `return Disposable.Empty;`. If ever you do this then you're probably making a mistake - you are typically making a blocking subscription (which you are). You're better off returning the subscription to an `Observable.Start(() => { ... }).Subscribe(observer)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want to use a [`AsyncSubject<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229363(v=vs.103).aspx):

```
IObservable<Result> SendRequest(Request request)
{
    var subject = new AsyncSubject<Result>();
    NetworkComms.SendReqeust(request, result =>
    {
        subject.OnNext(result);
        subject.OnCompleted();
    });
    return subject.AsObservable();
}
```

I should add that the interface you desire is a little odd.  If the semantics are "The moment I call this method, a request is made, and anybody who wants to can get the response at a later time," then consider just using `Task<Result>` instead of `IObservable<Result>`.

```
Task<Result> SendRequestAsync(Request request)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Result>();
    NetworkComms.SendReqeust(request, result => tcs.SetResult(result));
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Furthermore, consider putting this `Task<Result> SendRequestAsync(Request request)` method directly on your `NetworkComms` class.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. I'd seen the Subject classes but the stuff I'd read had said they shouldn't really be used in production code so I'd not considered them further. Looks like this is the way to go. The main point of the odd interface is so thet the action occurs even if the results are not subscribed to, but if the results are subscribed to (even after the action has completed) then the results are still obtained. It's not an expected scenario that the results would be subscribed to more than once, but I wanted to be clear that this would not retrigger the action just for completeness.

Comment: @Andy (Note I edited to use an `AsyncSubject<T>` instead of a `ReplaySubject<T>` - the former is more appropriate here because the sequence only contains one value.)  "Subjects shouldn't be used in production code" is a sweeping statement.  The reason people don't like subjects is that they are stateful.  But if what you need to do is something stateful, they are appropriate.  Just be wary of using them.  (See my suggestion in the last paragraph about an alternative.)

Comment: @Andy Subscribing to the returned observable multiple times will not invoke the network call multiple times.  The subscription has no side effects.  The call to SendRequestAsync has all the side effects.